# python {} is blue in visual studio code? when using {} in a statement, it actually displays the {} and whatevers in it

Tags: python

whenever I write a code say
x = 0

print("your number is {x}"

it actually prints {x} in visual studio code, instead of the value.

Comment: I guess you were going for [`f-strings`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/). You forgot the `f` in the start: `print(f"{x}")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This prints `{x}` because it's a simple string.
What you need is [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) as mentioned in comment.

Another way around is using [string format](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
print("your number is {}".format(x))
```

And an old-school:

```
print("your number is %s" % x)
```

Read [some more](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) for better understanding.